# Java: Cumulative sum from a list of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

For example there is a class similar to this:

```
class NameBudget {
  String name;
  Integer budget;
}
```

I am getting the list of budgets using the streams:

```
listOfNameBudgets.stream().map(NameBudget::getBudget()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

> How can I get the cumulative budget for each entry of the list using
>   streams?

I am avoiding to first create a list of budget and then do the cumulative. It should be possible to do it while creating the list from an object.

If the list was:

```
[ {
  "name":"A"
  "budget":1
},
{
  "name":"B"
  "budget":2
},{
  "name":"C"
  "budget":5
}
]
```

the output list would be `[1, 3, 8]`

Comment: The question is for the list of Integers, not the objects. I don't want extract the list of `budget` first and then do the cumulative.I would appreciate if you have the solution or not mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: The duplicate is about IntStream. You have a Stream. So you just need a way to transform a Stream into an IntStream. The javadoc is your friend: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-

Comment: There's no real reason to use streams: `int sum = 0; for (NameBudget n : list)  { list.add(sum += n.getBudget()); }`.

Comment: @AndyTurner 1) Composition, 2) parallel friendly, 3) higher level of abstraction

Comment: @Aomine 1) simple code. No need for 2).

Comment: @Aominè plz don't :) I am already fighting this higher level of abstraction in code review way too much...

Comment: @Eugene depends on what “level of abstraction” you’re seeing in code review. :)